# Are arduino libraries compatible on custom pcb?

Tags: arduino

I'm working on a project wherein I'm working on Arduino IDE and using Arduino Mega. I'm using third party libraries in the code such as ArduinoJson. Now, we wish to move our project to a custom pcb. Hence I wanted to know whether is it possible to run my code on the pcb, with this library? If not then is there any alternative for the code?(Im using the library to convert integers into a JSON object and upload it on a web dashboard)

Comment: The bulk of the Arduino Mega functionality is contained in the ATmega2560 chip. They would be more expensive to manufacture than the through-hole chips like the ATmega 328P chips found on boards like the Uno. Do you need 70 I/O pins or a substantial amount of memory?

Comment: The short answer is yes. The Arduino boards don't have too many other components, or at least nothing you couldn't add to your own PCB. The soldering of those tiny SMT pins crammed close together is more difficult and would make the project a little more costly. I like to shrink down and simplify when possible, but it depends on the project

Answer (score 0):

You can develop for any MCU that is supported by the Arduino IDE and there are ways to add more supported types.

All in all Arduino is just a simplyfied way of developing micro controller firmware.
They provide you with boards that have everything that is necessary to operate the MCU and to program it. Mainly power supply, USB interface, clock, breakout headers, bootloader...

You don't have to read 500 pages of manual, you don't have to set registers or do any bitwise operations. You don't have to bother with clock frequencies, compilers, makefiles, external programmers and whatnot.

In case you want to use an MCU that is not supported by the Arduino platform yet, checkout https://github.com/arduino/Arduino.